# C++: Magic Square: Checking two values in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, compare, magic-square

Forewarning: I'm very new at C++, and this is probably a very basic problem. I'm trying to read in a .txt file containing a series of numbers, put those into an array, then check the array to see whether or not it is a true magic square. I've done the first step, but a nested for loop keeps saying that I have repeating #s in the array. I don't know if my logic is wrong, or if I'm simply checking the wrong data.

```
...
bool flag=1;
int N;
string placeholder = "    ";



{
int array[10][10];
ifstream inputFile;
inputFile.open("MAGIC.txt");


inputFile>>N;
for (int x=0;x<N;x++){
    for (int y=0;y<N;y++){
        inputFile >> array[x][y];
    }
    }

for (int x=0;x<N;x++){
    for (int y=0;y<N;y++){
cout<<array[x][y]<<placeholder;
       }
    cout<<endl;
       }

//Everything above works great. 
//The following code changes "flag" to 0 every first loop
//I think it's checking the position instead of the value, but I don't know


for(int row=0;row<N;row++) {
for(int col=0;col<N;col++){

if(array[row]==array[col])  
flag=0;     break;
}
}

...
if(flag==1)
cout<<"Magic square"<<endl;
else
cout<<"No magic square"<<endl;    


  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line here:

```
if(array[row]==array[col])
```

You are using a 2D array called `array`.  When you give it only one index (*eg* `array[row]`) the compiler converts it to a pointer within that array.  So that line is testing pointers.  They will be equal only when `row` and `col` are equal.  This is guaranteed to happen because you loop over the same ranges, and so you will always clear `flag`.  I don't think this is what you intended.

I don't know what the logic is to test for a magic square, but you'll need to rethink.  I assume you need to compare individual values.

If you want to make sure your numbers are unique and lie between 1 and 100 try something like this:

```
char used[100] = {0};
int maxIdx = N * N - 1;

for( int x=0; x<N; x++ ) {
    for( int y=0; y<N; y++ ) {
        int idx = array[x][y] - 1;
        if( idx < 0 || idx > maxIdx || used[idx] ) {
            flag = 0;
            break;
        }
        used[idx] = 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check whether array is [magic square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square) or not you need to calculate sum for all rows and columns

here is code for this:

```
int flag = 1; // suppose it is magic square
int sum = 0;
for (int j=0; j<N; j++)
    sum += array[0][i]; // calculate sum for first row of array

for (int i=1; i<N; i++) // checking all rows
{
    int tsum = 0;
    for (int j=0; j<N; j++)
        tsum += array[i][j];
    if (tsum != sum)
    {
        flag = 0; break;
    }
}
if (flag)
{
    for (int j=0; i<N; i++) // checking all columns
    {
        int tsum = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
            tsum += array[i][j];
        if (tsum != sum)
        {
            flag = 0; break;
        }
    }
    // here you need to add code to check 2 diagonals
}
```

but note: you code has more problems

1. you're reading N from file, but array initialization is done via const 10, what if N will be 10000?
2. Arrays in c/c++ usually indexed as array[row][column], not [x][y] as in your case